# what is wrong with SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, apache-jena

I am trying to check if there are two individuals connected by the relation B , and have relation c with the same element

ASK{

```
{?x :B ?y}filter not exist{?x :c ?t1, ?y :c ?t2 ,t1 ≠ t2 }

}
```

Comment: If you want that they HAVE relation c, why `not exists`? Once, this is clear, all you need to do is fix the syntax: the commas are not OK there, and if you still want to filter out, then it should be `filter not exists`.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov  so is it  acceptable to put t1 ≠ t2  in the filter ? what is the syntax of not equal ? how to write it

Comment: It's `!=` . I would suggest that you refer to the [SPARQL specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) at least for the basic syntax

Comment: see the answer for some other syntax issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood right, the query you are trying to write should look like this:

```
ASK{
?x :B ?y;
:c ?t1 .
?y :c ?t2 .
filter (t1 != t2 )
}
```

Please note that with a such query, `x` and `y` might just as well be classes, and not individuals.

Comment: there was error in the query  it is t1 " ?x  :c  ?t1 " instead of t2, i correct it